# Generate pairs having the same attributes from list

Tags: algorithm, reduction

Assume you have a list of items, each with a set of attributes.

What is an efficient algorithm for **generating all pairs from the list having the same attributes?**

For example, given a list:

```
[('item1', {'a','b'}), ('item2', {'a'}), ('item3', {'c','b'}), ('item4', {'b'})]
```

We should return the following list of four pairs, out of the total possible six:

```
('item1', 'item2') # both have attribute 'a'
('item1', 'item3') # both have attribute 'b'
('item1', 'item4') # both have attribute 'b'
('item3', 'item4') # both have attribute 'b'
```

Now, the trivial approach would be to first generate the list of all possible `n(n+1)/2` pairs, and then filter out those without similar attributes, but I suspect this approach is inefficient, especially if the number of pairs is very large.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any programming language requirements?

Comment: @trincot - I'm currently using python, but it's the algorithm I'm really after.

Comment: First idea that comes to my mind is to construct a HashMap<Attribute, Item>, possible in O(numberOfAttributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a two phase algorithm:

```
arr = [('item1', {'a','b'}), ('item2', {'a'}), ('item3', {'c','b'}), ('item4', {'b'})]

# 1. create map with for each attribute the list of items that have it
mp = {}
for lst in arr:
    for prop in lst[1]:
        if prop not in mp: mp[prop] = []
        mp[prop].append(lst[0])

# 2. for each attribute: add the pairs of items to the result set
result = set()
for prop in mp:
    items = mp[prop]
    # collect all pairs in items list
    for p1 in range(len(items)):
        for p2 in range(p1+1,len(items)):
            result.add((items[p1],items[p2]))

print (result)
```

Output:

```
{('item1', 'item4'), ('item1', 'item2'), ('item3', 'item4'), ('item1', 'item3')}
```